# SWTO to x iOS translate

Tags: swift, xamarin.ios

I am trying from iOS and use it Xamarin Forms..issue is that.i don't know swift at all..

```
@objc func scanDocument()
        {
            let testViewController = ViewControllerCamer()
            testViewController.delegate = self
            present(scannler, animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: It's the delegate pattern. See how it's done with `DidSelectAnnotationView` in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/delegates-protocols-and-events I don't use Xamarin, but I guess it's the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xamarin we need to implement the protocol like following

```
public class MyDelegate : VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate
{
    public override void DidFinish(VNDocumentCameraViewController controller, VNDocumentCameraScan scan)
    {
        base.DidFinish(controller, scan);
       //do something you want
    }

    public override void DidCancel(VNDocumentCameraViewController controller)
    {
        base.DidCancel(controller);
    }

    public override void DidFail(VNDocumentCameraViewController controller, NSError error)
    {
        base.DidFail(controller, error);
    }
}
```

```
VNDocumentCameraViewController control = new VNDocumentCameraViewController();

control.Delegate = new MyDelegate();
```

Comment: It seems another issue . You coudl create a new thread with more details so that I can help you better :)